# One off the advantages of the bootstrap is that i don't have to worry about having a good estimator?

Tags: bootstrap, estimators

I'm learning about the theory of estimators and saw that sometimes the analytical formula of the estimator has to be diferent off the formula for the parameter, for example the standart deviation, and is sometimes difficult to get a good estimator. Can I in this cases just use bootstrap in the sample with the same formula I'm going to use for the parameter? For example if I want to estimate the first quantile of the population, can I just bootstrap with the first quantile? So one of the uses of the bootstrap is to help when no good estimator is available?

Comment: The value of the bootstrap is more when (i)  you don't gave a good way of getting standard errors (or CIs etc) and/or (ii) you dont have a suitable distributional model. It doesn't necessarily mean that the estimators is poor. Yes, sometimes that means relying on broad /large sample properties like the law of large numbers to choose consistent estimators